# SQL Select after character /

Tags: mysql, sql, select, character

I'd like to select everything AFTER a certain character (/) that is placed on the most right side.

I'v in CSV_COL(3) this text 200/100 or 50/10 ot 10/5 etc.. and i need to uso only number to the right of /

i try to use how i've found to forum

```
select right([CSV_COL(3)], charindex('/', reverse([CSV_COL(3)])) - 1)
```

But

> Impossibile valutare l'espressione "select right('200/100', charindex('/', reverse('20...". Errore: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select right('200/100', charindex('/', reverse('200/100')) - 1)' at line 1"

can anyone help me please?
best regards

Comment: Hello Stefano Linguari, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please tag your question with the database that you are using; sql-server, mysql, oracle...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the number after the last slash, you can use [MySQL string function `substring_index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
select substring_index(mycol, '/', -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just created a table table1 having field tblfield1 which have following records ->
2/6
50/10
10/50
200/100
4310/5501

And just run this query ->
select  right(tblfield1,length(tblfield1)-locate('/',tblfield1)) from table1;

Result->
10
50
100
5501

I think this is what you want.